# Save attachment custom fields on front end

Tags: custom-field, forms, attachments, post-meta, attachment-fields-to-edit

I have a front end post form that lets users upload multiple photos and on there I have 2 input fields to try and save custom meta data for each attachment -

```
$vid_pix = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'vid_pix', false);

if (!empty($vid_pix)) {
foreach ($vid_pix as $vP) {
$Pt = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', true);
$Por = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_order', true);

echo '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($vP) . '" alt=""/>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="photo_order" class="photo_order" value="'.$Por.'" />';
echo '<input type="text" name="photo_time" class="photo_time" value="'.$Pt.'"/>'; 
}
 }
```

When the form is submitted I am trying to save it using the following (I commented out failed attempts) -

```
//$Pt = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'photo_time', false);
//$Por = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'photo_order', false);  

// GET ATTACHMENT IDS
if (!empty($vid_pix)) {
foreach ($vid_pix as $vP) {

$post_id = $vP;
$meta = $_POST['attachments'][ $post_id ]['photo_time'];
update_post_meta($post_id, 'photo_time', $meta);
$meta_two = $_POST['attachments'][$post_id]['photo_order'];
update_post_meta($post_id, 'photo_order', $meta_two);

update_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', $attachment['attachments'][$vP]['photo_time']);
update_post_meta($vP, 'photo_order', $attachment['attachments'][$vP]['photo_order']); 

//$Pt = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'photo_time', false);
//$Por = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'photo_order', false);
//$Pt = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', true);
//$Por = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_order', true);

//update_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', $Pt);
//update_post_meta($vP, 'photo_order', $Por);
//update_post_meta($v_Id, '_photo_time', $newvidPix);                            
//add_post_meta($v_Id, 'photo_time', $Pt, false);
```

However I can not get it to work. Using the following code in functions.php I am able to get everything working on the backend though --

```
 // ADD FIELDS
        function mytheme_attachment_fields( $fields, $post ) {  
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'photo_time', true);
            $fields['photo_time'] = array(
                'label' => 'photo time',
                'input' => 'text',
                'value' => $meta,
                'show_in_edit' => true,
            );

            $meta_two = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'photo_order', true);
            $fields['photo_order'] = array(
                'label' => 'photo order',
                'input' => 'text',
                'value' => $meta_two,
                'show_in_edit' => true,
            ); 
            return $fields;         
        }
        add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'mytheme_attachment_fields', 10, 2 );

        // Update custom field on save
        function mytheme_update_attachment_meta($attachment){
            global $post;
              update_post_meta($post->ID, 'photo_time', $attachment['attachments'][$post->ID]['photo_time']);
              update_post_meta($post->ID, 'photo_order', $attachment['attachments'][$post->ID]['photo_order']);     
            return $attachment;
        }
        add_filter( 'edit_attachment', 'mytheme_update_attachment_meta', 4);

         // Update custom field via ajax
        function mytheme_media_xtra_fields() {
            $post_id = $_POST['id'];
            $meta = $_POST['attachments'][$post_id ]['photo_time'];
              update_post_meta($post_id , 'photo_time', $meta);
            $meta_two = $_POST['attachments'][$post_id ]['photo_order'];
              update_post_meta($post_id , 'photo_order', $meta_two);             
            clean_post_cache($post_id);
        }
        add_action('wp_ajax_save-attachment-compat', 'mytheme_media_xtra_fields', 0, 1);
```

Any ideas on how to get it saving on the front end? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the back-end, you're retrieving the data like this:

```
$meta = $_POST['attachments'][ $post_id ]['photo_time'];
$meta_two = $_POST['attachments'][$post_id]['photo_order'];
```

So on the front-end, you should set the field's `name` in this format: `attachments[<?= $vP ?>][KEY]` where `KEY` could be either `photo_order` or `photo_time`.

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="attachments[<?= $vP ?>][photo_order]" class="photo_order" value="'.$Por.'" />';
echo '<input type="text" name="attachments[<?= $vP ?>][photo_time]" class="photo_time" value="'.$Pt.'"/>';
```

**UPDATE**

Saving the data:

*Check the code in the **UPDATE #2** section below.*

Use that code in place of what you have (tried) — the code after this in your *question*:

> When the form is submitted I am trying to save it using the following
>   (I commented out failed attempts) -

**UPDATE #2**

It's probably preferred to wrap the code (for saving the data) in a function, like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_save_vid_pix_data' );
function my_save_vid_pix_data() {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['attachments'], $_POST['v_Id'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $atts = (array) $_POST['attachments'];
    $post_id = absint( $_POST['v_Id'] );
    $vid_pix = get_post_meta($post_id, 'vid_pix', false);

    foreach ((array) $vid_pix as $vP) {
        if ( ! isset( $atts[ $vP ] ) || ! is_array( $atts[ $vP ] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        update_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', $atts[ $vP ]['photo_time']);
        update_post_meta($vP, 'photo_order', $atts[ $vP ]['photo_order']);
    }
}
```

(Add that function to the theme's `functions.php` file.)

And add a hidden `input` field (named `v_Id`) after this `foreach` loop:

```
if (!empty($vid_pix)) {
foreach ($vid_pix as $vP) {
...
echo '<input type="text" name="attachments[<?= $vP ?>][photo_time]" class="photo_time" value="'.$Pt.'"/>'; 
}

echo '<input type="hidden" name="v_Id" value="' . $v_Id . '">';
 }
```

(Please refer to your *question* for the `$v_Id` variable.)

Comment: ok but how do I save it when submitting the form on the front end?

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried it but it still didnt save it.

Comment: Add `var_dump( $atts );` above the `foreach` loop in the code I provided for saving the data. Then see if the output is what you expected. You may also want to share it (temporarily) on Pastebin.com so that I can inspect the data. Try also to change the `attachments` to `attachments2` in the field's `name` and in the code I gave.

Comment: I've also updated the answer. Hopefully the update helps you.

Comment: Hi, quick question, is there a way to make the 1st key have the 2nd key's value, 2nd key to have the 3rd keys value, etc? Like shift the numbers back 1? I was trying to figure out with outputting the values - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277887/skip-first-value-for-variable-inside-of-foreach-loop-php/52280111#52280111 but instead of outputting that way, maybe I can save it that way?

Comment: @Rich sorry, I may have either forgotten about this or that I didn't really notice your last comment. But I've posted an answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277887/skip-first-value-for-variable-inside-of-foreach-loop-php). Check it out and let me know (if you still need help in saving it that way).